# Delete request in React with Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, axios

I'm trying to make a delete request in React with Axios. My backend is node. I'm having trouble passing the data properly through axios. It sucessfully [console.log(res)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elJAK.png) and hits the controller giving me the `Member sucessfully deleted` message. But when i refresh my page, the record is still there. I don't know what is causing that. 
This is my axios code in react:

```
onDelete(memberId) {
    axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/api/members', {id: memberId})
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            console.log('it works')
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

this is how i'm calling it:

```
<Table.Body>
    {this.state.members.map(member =>
        <Table.Row key={member._id}>
            <Table.Cell>{member.name}</Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>{member.email}</Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell> <Button icon='remove user' onClick={() => this.onDelete(member._id)}/></Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
    )}
</Table.Body>
```

this is my controller:

```
exports.delete_a_member = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params);
    Member.remove({
        _id: req.params.memberId
    }, function (err, member) {
    if (err)
        res.send(err);
    res.json({message: 'Member successfully deleted!!'});
    });
};
```

this is my route:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var members = require('../controllers/membersController');

    app.route('/api/members')
        .get(members.list_all_members)
        .post(members.create_a_member)
        .delete(members.delete_a_member);
};
```

Comment: You return the message if `if (err)` - as in if there's an error. Your logic is backwards. Log what's in the error.

Comment: I'd provide two separate paths for the `remove` callback. Right now, `res.json({message: 'Member...` fires regardless of whether there is an error or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `http://localhost:5000/api/members${memberId}` i tried and it worked, you can ask Jasser Abdel the system angel

Answer (score 0):

It seems **remove()** is deprecated in deleting a document from a collection in mongoDb. Try out **deleteOne()** method.
You can checkout how to use it in the documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/#db.collection.deleteOne

Comment: hey thanks! that's a good thing to notice. i tried it but it still isn't working for me. but that's a really good thing for me to keep in mind. thanks :-)